# Mesh is white when exporting to FBX . Cannot get original textures)

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image][image]So my model is mostly white wehn exporting to fbx.
I did manage to texture bake them but the result is not the same:
Top white is fbx, below is desired original look.
[image: THIS is the original model]

Comment: Hello ! Short answer is you can't export procedural textures. You mentioned you had trouble baking the textures. Where exactly did it fail ?

Comment: The baked textures where not the same quality , there was no reflective goggles and no shiny eyes etc.

Comment: Did you bake several maps, one for color, one for metalness, one for roughness, etc. ?

Comment: no. Just one diffuse per texture.

Comment: I am really a noob at texture baking...Any chance I can send you the model and you do a proper texture bake, if that works.

Comment: I dont mind paying paypal

Comment: Nope sorry but there are plenty of material about baking out there. Try the keywords : "Blender bake pbr" (for physically based rendering), for instance the first result : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdcodiuIwXM

Comment: i have been following it but dont know which bake type to use , i done one diffuse which gave some color but roughness bake did not???