# Help baking procedural textures

Tags: python, particles, graph-editor

So I tried baking some textures for my character and then exported the FBX to unreal.
Some textures dont have the shinyness or extra flavour in the texture.
Am bit of a noob when it comes to baking.
Please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From this link:

Comment: From this link you can see my model with textures:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253652/mesh-is-white-when-exporting-to-fbx-cannot-get-original-textures

Comment: When i bakle a procedural texture and import the fbx to unreal the texture is not as good/same. please help.